# How should one perform a calculation on the results of two Ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with two text fields. When the user changes the value of either one, I send two ajax requests, one for the value of each field, and then perform a calculation on the two results.

However, because they're asynchronous there's no way to know when they've finished, and I cant run the calculation in the callback function of either one because the other one might not have finished at that point.

Currently I'm declaring two global variables, calling the second request from the callback of the first, and calculating the result in the callback of the second.

This seems like really bad practice, especially seeing as they both query the same API - there's no reason to have the code written twice.
How can I restructure my code to improve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wanted to add that `Deferred` can help here:

```
var responses = [];

$.when(
    $.get("url1", function(response) {
        responses[0] = response;
    }),

    $.get("url2"), function(response) {
        responses[1] = response;
    })
).then( // will run when both are completed
    function() {
        alert(responses);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have both success handlers call the same function to handle the responses.  Let that function continue only if both responses have been received:

```
(function () {
    var response1 = null;
    var response2 = null;
    $.get("/url1", function(response) {
        response1 = response;
        processResponses();
    });
    $.get("/url2", function(response) {
        response2 = response;
        processResponses();
    });
    function processResponses() {
        if (response1 && response2) {
            // do something
        }
    }
})();
```

But if it were me, I'd just modify my server code so that one request is all that is necessary.

Comment: Running the code on the server is a pretty good idea, I've written my entire webapp so far client-side apart from a proxy script so moving some server-side would make sense in general.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code snippet, you have to define the function only once, using one public function.

```
function handleDualRequest(response){
   if(!handleDualRequest.lastResponse){ //If a last response doesn't exist, return;
       handleDualRequest.lastResponse = response;
       return;
   }
   var lastResponse = handleDualRequest.lastResponse;
   //Else: Two response texts, continue
   // Available response strings:
   response;
   lastResponse;

   //Finished function, reset variable:
   handleDualResponse.lastResponse = "";
}
```

If you have to support multiple dual calls, you can add a second parameter, and store the last response in an array `handleDualResponse.lastResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

Have two variables to indicate if the call is finished, set them to false before calling the Ajax.  Each ajax callback sets one of the variables to true, then calls a common function which examines the two variables.  If they are both true, it performs the computation.